# Knights tour in haskell getting a loop

Tags: loops, haskell, knights-tour

I'm in the process of coding the knight's tour function, and I'm as far as this where I'm getting an infinte loop in my ghci:

```
type Field = (Int, Int)

nextPositions:: Int -> Field -> [Field]
nextPositions n (x,y) = filter onBoard  
    [(x+2,y-1),(x+2,y+1),(x-2,y-1),(x-2,y+1),(x+1,y-2),(x+1,y+2),(x-1,y-2),(x-1,y+2)]  
    where onBoard (x,y) = x `elem` [1..n] && y `elem` [1..n]

type Path = [Field]

knightTour :: Int -> Field -> [Path]
knightTour n start = [posi:path | (posi,path) <- tour (n*n)]
                         where tour 1 = [(start, [])]
                               tour k = [(posi', posi:path) | (posi, path) <- tour (k-1), posi' <- (filter (`notElem` path) (nextPositions n posi))]
```

F.e. knightTour 10 (4,4) does not give an output!
Any advise?

Comment: `knightTour 10` is a 10x10 field, so if on average you have for example 3 possible moves, the search tree takes 3^100, so 5e47 possibilities... At most there are eight possibilities (initially), but except for the first move, there are at most seven. But that is still a gigantic tree.

Comment: Okay, now  i tried knightTour 6 (1,1) and it appears to also not find an logic ending, any suggestions for improvement in my code? I'm trying to visit every square only once and none two times .

Comment: I think the `onBoard` is too slow. You should look for an array, for example of booleans (or use for small boards up to 8x8 a 64-bit integer to encode what pieces have been visited).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think one of the main problems is checking if you have visited a square. This takes too much time. You should look for a data structure that makes that more efficient.

For small boards, for example up to 8×8, you can make use of a 64-bit integer for that. A 64-bit can be seen as 64 booleans that each can represent whether the knight already has visited that place.

we thus can implement this with:

```
{-# LANGUAGE BangPatterns #-}

import Data.Bits(testBit, setBit)
import Data.Word(Word64)

testPosition :: Int -> Word64 -> (Int, Int) -> Bool
testPosition !n !w (!r, !c) = testBit w (n*r + c)

setPosition :: Int -> (Int, Int) -> Word64 -> Word64
setPosition !n (!r, !c) !w = setBit w (n*r + c)

nextPositions :: Int -> Word64 -> (Int, Int) -> [(Int, Int)]
nextPositions !n !w (!x, !y) = [ c
  | c@(x', y') <- [(x-1,y-2), (x-1,y+2), (x+1,y-2), (x+1,y+2), (x-2,y-1), (x-2,y+1), (x+2,y-1), (x+2,y+1)]
  , x' >= 0
  , y' >= 0
  , x' < n
  , y' < n
  , not (testPosition n w c)
  ]

knightTour :: Int -> (Int, Int) -> [[(Int, Int)]]
knightTour n p0 = go (n*n-1) (setPosition n p0 0) p0
    where go 0 _ _ = [[]]
          go !k !w !ps = [
              (ps':rs)
            | ps' <- nextPositions n w ps
            , rs <- go (k-1) (setPosition n ps' w) ps'
            ]

main = print (knightTour 6 (1,1))
```

If I compile this with the `-O2` flag and run this locally for a 5×5 board where the knight starts at (1,1), all the solutions are generated in 0.32 seconds. For a 6×6 board, it takes 2.91 seconds to print the first solution, but it takes forever to find all solutions that start at (1,1). For an 8×8 board, the first solution was found in 185.76 seconds:

```
[(0,3),(1,5),(0,7),(2,6),(1,4),(0,2),(1,0),(2,2),(3,0),(4,2),(3,4),(4,6),(5,4),(6,2),(5,0),(3,1),(2,3),(3,5),(2,7),(0,6),(2,5),(1,3),(0,1),(2,0),(3,2),(2,4),(0,5),(1,7),(3,6),(4,4),(5,6),(7,7),(6,5),(7,3),(6,1),(4,0),(5,2),(7,1),(6,3),(7,5),(6,7),(5,5),(4,7),(6,6),(7,4),(5,3),(7,2),(6,0),(4,1),(3,3),(2,1),(0,0),(1,2),(0,4),(1,6),(3,7),(4,5),(5,7),(7,6),(6,4),(4,3),(5,1),(7,0)]
```

It is however not a good idea to solve this with a brute force approach. If we assume an average branching factor of ~6 moves, then for a 6×6 board, we have already 1.031×10<sup>28</sup> possible sequences we have to examine for a 6×6 board.

It is better to work with a divide and conquer approach. It is easy to split a board like 8×8 into four 4×4 boards. Then you determine places where you can hop from one board to another, and then you solve the subproblems for a 4×4 board. For small boards, you can easily store the solutions to go from any square to any other square on a 4×4 board, and then *reuse* these for all quadrants, so you save computational effort, by not calculating this a second time, especially since you do not need to store symmetrical queries multiple times. If you know how to go from (1,0) to (2,3) on a 4×4 board, you can easily use this to go from (3,0) to (2,3) on the same board, just by mirroring this.